# Is there a way in VBA to copy a row to another worksheet, if one of the cells within the row contains "Color AP"?

Tags: excel, vba

Basically what I have is one sheet in excel that has a huge chart that says Product XX is running, and what types of checks it had to do before it passed. I want to copy every row that has a Color check on it, however this could be in different columns down the row as it may not have been the first check that was done.

I have already run through multiple different things running into similair and different issues:
.AutoFilter: Whatever column is filtered first takes away from other possible columns that may have had a "Color" check in them. I was building one from someone elses but then thought through the logic and realized it wouldn't work.

```
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim ColorAP() As String
    Set wsData = Sheets("Reactor 8 New Way")    'Copying FROM this worksheet (it contains your data)
    Set wsDest = Sheets("Color AP Analysis")
    ReDim ColorAP(1 To 3)
    ColorAP(1) = "Color AP"
    ColorAP(2) = "Color AP"
    ColorAP(3) = "Color AP"
    With wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .AutoFilter 1, ColorAP, xlFilterValues   'Filter using the array, this avoids having to do a loop`

        'Copy the filtered data (except the header row) and paste it as values
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Copy
        wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False     'Remove the CutCopy border
        .AutoFilter     'Remove the filter
    End With
```

The issue I have each try is not being able to look at each column before copying. I really do not want to do a huge nested if statement with a loop that checks each column per row to see if it says "Color"
I'd rather check each column to find all the "Color" and copy those rows, however some products would get checked for "Color" more than once, and I dont want duplicates.
Also for the copied rows I do not want all of the columns across the page only the first 26. 
I am doing this on a work laptop that does not have the capacity for running hundreds of lines of code, so on all my other codes I try to find the smallest way to do it. 
Picture of sheet below

[image: https://imgur.com/a/aFPFaOG]

Comment: Since you're checking for a string, you may want to capture your whole dataset as an `variant array` (`data_arr`) then loop through that, which is quite quick, and capture the row numbers in a separate array (`match_arr`).  utilize the `match_arr` to make cell references and then `.value=.value` or `copy/paste` depending on need.

Comment: Cyril's approach is probably quickest, though the `Find` method would be another.

Answer (score 0):

quick example of my comments (untested):

```
dim rng as range, rc as long, cc as long, i as long
dim r as long, c as long, match_arr as variant, data_arr as variant
set rng = activesheet.usedrange
rc = rng.rows.count
cc = rng.columns.count
data_arr = rng.value
redim match_arr(rc) 'safety net in case all have it
i = 1
for c = 1 to cc
    for r = 1 to rc
        if ucase(data_arr(r,c)) = "COLOR AP" then
            match_arr(i) = r
            i = i+1
            exit for
        end if
    next r
next c
```

The `exit for` in the row-loop, since you're only looking for rows to copy, would be your key to speed.  You can then use `rows(match_arr())` to loop and `dest.value=src.value`.