# Excel VBA Makro compare and copy

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a row from a sheet into a third sheet, if the ServerID exists in both sheets

```
Sub XDDXH()

Dim i As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 2 To 3318

    For z = 8 To 731

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(i, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(z, 8).Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("i:i").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("j:j")
        j = j + 1
    End If

    Next z

Next i

End Sub
```

With this code I get runtime error 1004.
This is my first time working with VBA.

Comment: `Range(i, 1)` and `Range(z, 8)` - use `Cells` instead of `Range`.

Comment: Is `Range("j:j")` meant to refer to the variable `j` rather than column J? If so, remove from quotes.

Comment: ^ Same for `Range("i:i")`. Or use `Rows` instead of `Range` here.

Comment: You need to increment `j` before you copy, or add `j=1` beforehand. When `j` = 0 then this will fail.

Comment: @BigBen - I think you've found enough things now to warrant an answer, if you're in the mood.

Comment: @SJR working on it :)

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions if i execute this now i don't get any errors it takes a while but nothing is written in Sheet3

Comment: Have you tried the answers below?

Comment: @SJR i'm trying the one from cyrill but i think excel crashed

Comment: @AntonBerdi most likely because it takes a lot to go through all of those iterations... i posted something similar about 30 minutes ago and will pull a link about capturing the range as a `variant array`... [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58645000/3233363).

Comment: Could just be that's quite slow as the loops together constitute a lot of iterations. @BigBen's should be quicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be simplified to one loop with `CountIf` (untested, but I think I got everything). You could also use `Match` if you prefer that.

```
Sub XDDXH()
    Dim lookInRng as Range
    Set lookInRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H8:H731")

    Dim sourceRng as Range
    Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A3318")

    Dim rng as Range
    For Each rng in sourceRng
       If Application.CountIf(lookInRng, rng.Value) > 0 Then
           Dim j as Long
           j = j + 1
           rng.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & j)
       End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Presumably declaring the variable inside the loop makes no difference to anything?

Comment: Yep. `Dim` statements aren't executed.

Comment: Just a suggestion to improve on this to OP: He noted in a comment it runs, but takes a while. Going through memory would significantly improve this runtime (arrays, dictionary and union on ranges (whilst the latter could be avoided since only values are wanted))

Comment: @JvdV yes, and also not copying the entire row. Though have to confirm with OP that only values are wanted (did I miss a comment somewhere)?

Comment: @SJR it makes quite a difference when you later want to take the loop body into its own procedure scope. Much easier to refactor code when you don't have to hunt down variables in a giant wall of declarations at the top of the procedure.

Comment: My last statement on values was maybe more an assumption ;) (seen so many who don't know about value transfers)

Comment: @BigBen how do i end the loop? you still include next i

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - fair enough. I'm guilty of those walls, but they do at least have the advantage of not having to hunt down the definition of any variables.

Comment: @SJR I'm sorry, not buying that. Declaring variables where they're relevant *is* how you avoid needing to constantly scroll up to the wall of declarations, and then back down to where you were. When variables are declared in the context they're used in, you never need to hunt them down.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - can't say it's ever troubled me, but then I'm not a professional developer, but will bear in mind henceforth.

Comment: @AntonBerdi actually, it can be just `Next` there's no reason to specify `i` or `rng` or whatever the loop variable is. The "compiler" doesn't care - it's only there for human readability. If you can refactor your code to avoid nested loops then a simple `Next` is all you'll ever need.

Answer (score 2):

Will implement a couple changes and consolidate the general consensus from comments:

```
'"As Integer" will get silently converted to "As Long" so just start with Long to save processing power
Dim i As Long, j as long, z as long
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet, ws3 as Worksheet
'setting sheets to just be cleaner and easier to write
set ws1 = Sheets(1) 'using the index, but could be Sheets("sheet1"), etc.
set ws2 = sheets(2)
set ws3 = sheets(3)
j = 1 'need this or you'll default to j=0 which doesn't work for a range in excel

For i = 2 To 3318
    For z = 8 To 731
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(z, 8).Value Then
            ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.Rows(j)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next z
Next i
```

Note that `Range("A1")` and `Cells(1,1)` are syntactically different ways of saying the same thing.  Be careful to not interchange those.

If utilizing a variable, you do not use quotations, e.g., variable `j` is iterated on a new sheet and you wouldn't write `Range("j:j") as that will be the whole column 'J` in the worksheet (yes, lowercase doesn't technically matter for that).

Comment: Small point but you could put `j=j+1` before the copy line and then you could do away with a whole line `j=1`.

Comment: Will thumbs you up for that @SJR though I was thinking explaining why `j` was 0 would be helpful in the way written.